# Laravel Email sending

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid

I am using laravel-sendgrid-driver (https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container ).

It sends email for normal Text. I need to send some 4-5 lines subject. But unable to send email. Shows Errors like "Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, string given,"

```
$emailTemplate = str_replace($searchArray, $tmpVal, $email);

 Mail::send( [], $emailTemplate, function ($message){
                $message->to($userDetail[0]->email)
                        ->from('info@test.in', 'test-Technologies')
                        ->subject('Forgot Password');
            });
```

How to resolve " Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, string given,"

Comment: How to set " ->setBody($emailTemplate);" Email Body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send` method accepts three arguments.

**First**, the name of a **`view`** that contains the e-mail message.

**Secondly**, an **`array of data`** you wish to pass to the view.

**Lastly**, a Closure callback which receives a message instance, allowing you to customize the recipients, subject, and other aspects of the mail message:

```
Mail::send('viewfilename', ['name' => 'Abhilash KM'], function ($m) use ($userDetail) {
            $m->from('info@test.in', 'test-Technologies');
            $m->to($userDetail[0]->email)->subject('Forgot Password');
        });
```